# Почему не записывается буквенное выражение?

Tags: php

```
      $id = $user->id;
      $fff = "fdsds5455f";
      R::exec( 'UPDATE user SET hash = '.$fff.' WHERE id ='.$id.'' );
```

на месте переменной $fff должен быть хеш для проверки пользователя, ну даже это не вводит строки содержащие буквы... только цифры

1. фрейм **RedBeanPHP**
2. строка в бд  varchar(191)

Comment: Если это хэш, то он может состоять только символов  шестнадцатеричного алфавита, куда "s" не входит. Да и начинаться шестнадцатеричиное число наверняка должно с "0x".

Comment: можете привести пример простейшего генератора рандомной строчки?

Answer (score 0):

Так как это строка, то hash нужно обернуть в кавычки

```
 R::exec( 'UPDATE user SET hash = "'.$fff.'" WHERE id ='.$id.'' );
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: А с этим можешь подсказать? надо вывести id по email из таблицы user    
 $id = R::find('user', "id = ?", $data['email']);

Comment: Сравнивать нужно не id и $data['email'], а email и $data['email'].
Что-то вроде
 $id = R::find('user', "email = '?'", $data['email']);

Answer (score 0):

**Dfdg Dfghgfd**, простейший генератор рандомной строки.

```
<?php
function getRandomStr($length = 10) {
  $cmap = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $clen = strlen($cmap);
  $srnd = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
     $srnd .= $cmap[rand(0, $clen - 1)];
  }
  return $srnd;
}

echo getRandomStr(13);
?>
```

Comment: спасибки тебе))